# Birdeye Reviews Script not working properly in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, google-chrome

So I have a script posted on a WordPress site both in the body of a page and in the footer. The body script works fine, but the footer doesn't show up and only in Google Chrome browser. It is a Review Badge and you can see it here [SemBro Designs](http://sembrodesigns.com/) or in the body of the [Reviews](http://sembrodesigns.com/reviews/) page. You might also notice that it doesn't work properly on the reviews page. One is in the body at the top and second one should be in the footer. My thought maybe because it is already shown in the body and so it doesn't repeat.

What can I do to resolve this?

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://birdeye.com/embed/576939136/1"  /></script>
<img id="revz-widget" height="80" width="133"></img>
```

Is it something I'm doing when posting the script or is it the original source?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by it does not work?

Comment: It is not showing up properly, not visible. I know it there and the source should be fine, but just not showing up.

Comment: Well, I'm still having this issue, so for now I just removed the java script from the footer, it is still in the Reviews section. If anyone can help that would be great. By the way does [Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) act differently in [Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome)?